# Opening a different tab on button click and redirecting to another html

Tags: html, angularjs, mean-stack

I know there are similar questions, but the answers and suggestions are not working for me and i am unable to understand the error.

On click of a button, I want to load another HTML in a new tab. When I try, "www.google.com", I am able to do so. But when I try to load an HTML which I have, I am unable to do so.

Here is the relevant html code :

```
<div id="button">
    <a href="www.google.com"
       target="_blank"><input type="button" value="Visualisation"></a><!-- THIS WORKS -->
    <form action="/Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/public/views/tree_custom.html"
          target="_blank">
        <input type="submit"
               value="Go to Google" />
    </form><!-- THIS Fails -->
    <input type=button
           onClick="location.href='tree_custom.html'"
           value='click here'
           target="_blank"><!-- THIS Fails -->
</div>
```

The error I get is this, which I am not able to debug :

> 

```
Error: Not Found
        at /Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/app.js:41:13
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (/Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
        at /Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
        at Function.process_params (/Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
        at next (/Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
        at /Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
        at next (/Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
        at Function.handle (/Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
        at router (/Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular, I would suggest using [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick). Then you can bind a method that's defined in your controller to the `ng-click`. Which will open a new tab with the desired url when the user clicks your button.

```
body.html
<div ng-controller="exampleCtrl as ctrl">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.directToGoogle()"></button>
</div>

index.js
angular.module('exampleModule', [])
       .controller('exampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', 
             function ($scope, $window) {
                  $scope.directToGoogle = function () {
                        $window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank')
                  }])
```

This would be a simple and contrived example of how to bind a method to `ng-click` and do what you described in your question earlier.

Comment: could you please share a small example of what you are saying

Comment: @Tarun I added an example to my answer, I hope that clarifies what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onclick="window.open('tree_custom.html')"` with `target="_blank"` instead of using `location.href`

```
<div id="button">
          <a href="www.google.com"
             target="_blank"><input type="button" value="Visualisation"></a><!-- THIS WORKS -->
          <form action="/Users/tarun/Work/marchDemo/public/views/tree_custom.html"
                target="_blank">
              <input type="submit"
                     value="Go to Google" />
          </form><!-- THIS works -->
          <input type=button  onclick="window.open('tree_custom.html')"
                 value='click here'
                 target="_blank"><!-- THIS WORKS -->
      </div>
```

Check working plunker :  https://plnkr.co/edit/PQk5al?p=preview

Comment: hi, Thanks:) i tried this method, but it doesn't work. Even the plnkr example you shared gives an internal server error.

Comment: tree_custom.html   I have used redirection for third input button only.

Comment: Where you have hosted ur HTML file ?

Comment: @Tarun I just read this comment, if you're experiencing an internal server error, then like Anil says, you need to host your files

Comment: @ShermanHui and anil - Thanks..  ya. i had to host it or include it in another folder because it had javascript embedded inside it. Thanks both of you